# How to prevent downstream filters from overriding the HTTP response body

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm using Spring boot ControllerAdvisor class to write the JSON response body of the `HttpServletResponse` object due to unavoidable reason. Still my downstream Tomcat filters(Over which I don't have any control) override my response.

How can I prevent them from overriding this status. Setting `isCommited` to `true` seems to be a dirty hack even though I couldn't figure how to do so.

Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

```
// Inside the controller advisor
private void writeHttpResponseForTechnicalErrors(HttpServletRequest httpRequest,
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse, ResponseEntity responseEntity) {

        String jsonResponse jsonResponse = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(responseEntity.getBody());
        httpResponse.getWriter().write(jsonResponse);
}
```

Edit:

I was able to set `isCommited` to `true` with below. Still doesn't feel like this is a very good approach. Lemme know :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using ContentCachingResponseWrapper from spring

```
ContentCachingResponseWrapper wrapper = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponseObject);
filterchain.doFilter(httpServletRequestObject, wrapper);
byte[] data = wrapper.getContentAsByteArray();
response.getOutputStream().write(data);
```

maybe it will help